# iOS 11: Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException requestFocusAtPoint: called while no input device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

Crash reported on App store app with the exception:

`NSInternalInconsistencyException requestFocusAtPoint: called while no input device`

Details of one such instance:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1b144bef8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b0619a40 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1b136006c +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]
3  Foundation                     0x1b1e4c3e0 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  MicroBlink                     0x100f7d068 (Missing)
5  UIKitCore                      0x1ddc8d308 __accelCallback_block_invoke
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b0e836c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b0e84484 _dispatch_client_callout
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b0e309ec _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1b13da1bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1b13d5084 __CFRunLoopRun
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1b13d45b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
12 GraphicsServices               0x1b3648584 GSEventRunModal
13 UIKitCore                      0x1ddccf558 UIApplicationMain
14 ID-Pal                         0x10059eaf0 main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b0e94b94 start
```

> 0  ID-Pal                         0x100790bfc
>   CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4313254908 1  ID-Pal
>   0x100790bfc CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4313254908 2  ID-Pal
>   0x100790ab8 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4313254584 3  ID-Pal
>   0x1007807f8 CLSHandler + 4313188344 4  ID-Pal
>   0x10078ec04 **CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4313246724 5 
>   libdispatch.dylib              0x1b0e84484 _dispatch_client_callout +
>   16 6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b0e31610
>   _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56 7  ID-Pal                         0x10078e698 CLSExceptionRecord + 4313245336 8  ID-Pal
>
>   0x10078e4c0 CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 4313244864 9  ID-Pal
>
>   0x10078e0d4 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4313243860 10 libc++abi.dylib
>
>   0x1b060d0fc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 11 libc++abi.dylib
>
>   0x1b060d188 std::terminate() + 84 12 libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x1b0619da4 _destroyAltHandlerList + 10 13 libdispatch.dylib
>
>   0x1b0e84498 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 14 libdispatch.dylib
>
>   0x1b0e309ec _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1068 15
>   CoreFoundation                 0x1b13da1bc
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 12 16 CoreFoundation                 0x1b13d5084 __CFRunLoopRun + 1964 17
>   CoreFoundation                 0x1b13d45b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
>   18 GraphicsServices               0x1b3648584 GSEventRunModal + 100 19
>   UIKitCore                      0x1ddccf558 UIApplicationMain + 212 20
>   ID-Pal                         0x10059eaf0 main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
>   21 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b0e94b94 start + 4

Did anyone face the same issue? What could be the reason for failure?

Comment: Please share more information. ex.Code, How crash happened

Comment: This happens only in production though and don't know the exact reason for this cause.

Comment: I have got the same crash, please share the solution if you find it